# Files uploaded to bim 360 doc mgmt via Forge web service do not appear when logged in to BIM 360 website?

Tags: autodesk-forge, rest-client, autodesk-bim360

Following the tutorial found at this url:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/

the files appear (to have storage ids? and versions?) when the folder items are viewed from a custom web page using the web service to 'GET' folder items. However the items do not load into a viewer, nor do they appear when logged in to the BIM 360 Document Management web site view. Can these items be either fixed or removed?

Comment: I am trying to understand better on your question. Which folder the file is uploaded? Could you share the response payload when GET folder items by API and a snapshot of that folder on BIM 360 website?  it will help to know more contexts of the issue. Please remove any information what is confidential to you.  It is also a way to send email to forge.help@autodesk.com if you do not want to post these information in public

Comment: Thanks Xiaodong, Your comment prompted me to look further at the details of the response  object. In the 'Included' section, each item is iterated and under attributes - extension - data, there is a processState and extractionState. The first shows as "Processing_Complete" , second "Failed" for the objects that do not appear as functional from my initial question. I suspect the file upload is not completing for files of any substantial size.